# if else with 2 text variables

Tags: jquery, text, if-statement

I have two variables in a table.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td class="cell1">10</td><td class="cell2">5</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now i would like to say, if the number in .cell2 is smaller than the number in .cell1 change the color of .cell2 red.

Comment: Are you using Razor, asp.net?

Comment: @XyanEwing but jQuery is and that's...uh you know, client side (:

Answer (score 5):

Fetch the contents of each cell with [`.text`](http://api.jquery.com/text/). Convert to numbers with [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), and add or remove some CSS class that applies the requisite style conditionally with [`.toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/):

```
var isSmaller=parseInt($(".cell2").text(),10) < parseInt($(".cell1").text(),10);
$(".cell2").toggleClass("red", isSmaller);
```

In this example I 'm assuming this additional CSS:

```
.red { background-color: red }
```

Comment: you forgot radix in parseInt(number, radix) but the rest is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You could get the string value of the inner text using the text() operator:

```
cell10 = $('.cell10').text();
cell2  = $('.cell2').text();
```

Then use the parseInt function:

```
if (parseInt(cell10) > parseInt(cell2)) {
    ...
}
```

**EDIT** Jon beat me to it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/knnga/) and the relevenat part:

```
function doStuff() {
   var $v1 = $('.cell1').text();
   var $v2 = $('.cell2').text();   

   /* debug output */
   $('#result').text("result: v1: " + $v1 + ", v2: " + $v2);

   if (parseInt($v1, 10) > parseInt($v2, 10)) {
       $('.cell2').css("background-color", "red");

       /* debug output */
       $('#result').append("</br> cell1 > cell2 == true");
    }        
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    doStuff();
 });
```

Comment: I forgot to say that the table data repeat, now the script does not work anymore. It will change the background color everywhere. `<table>
<tr>
<td class="cell1">10</td><td class="cell2">5</td>
<td class="cell1">7</td><td class="cell2">3</td>
</tr>
</table>`

Comment: sorry, like this.. `<table>
<tr>
<td class="cell1">10</td><td class="cell2">5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="cell1">7</td><td class="cell2">3</td>
</tr>
</table>`

Comment: uh, there is wrong fiddle link, just read accepted answers instead of mine.